# What is the net running time of the below expression?

Tags: runtime, time-complexity, big-o

For a recursive algorithm, I came up with the following expression to calculate the running time. But I am not clear on how to simplify this and express in `Big-O` notation.

[image]

If it is just `4k`, then I know that it is simply a GP series and we can take the last term which is `4n` as the worst case running time. Help me understand how to deal with `(k+1)` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to simplify the term a little bit

```
Σk=0,...,n 4k(k+1) < Σk=0,...,n 4k(n+1) = (n+1) Σk=0,...,n 4k
```

So this is in `O(n⋅4n)`. And this bound is tight since `4n(n+1)` is part of the sum.

Notice: what you mean by "running time" is usually called "complexity".